# What is the history behind having peanuts in mission control during critical missions?

Tags: mars, insight, jpl

The InSight mission livestream showed a jar of peanuts with what appears to be the MarCO logo.

[image]

Why is was this a significant shot in the livestream? Is there history behind this?

Comment: Welcome to Space! They did briefly explain the peanut tradition during the coverage, but I'm sure there are plenty of people here that can give a very detailed explanation!

Comment: I could swear someone here (Mark Adler?) already posted about this recently, but I can't find it.

Comment: @HDE226868 Understood. I have used all my upvotes for today so I will give you one tomorrow. I will take a look at the incoming responses as well. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out [this goes way back to the 1960s](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/10022/lucky-peanuts/). Landing on a celestial body isn't easy; JPL had suffered a series of failures during the [*Ranger* missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranger_program), some during launch and others further on in each mission. For *Ranger 7*, someone on the team (credit has been given to both Dick Wallace and [Harrison Schurmeier](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/vintagespace/2018/05/04/peanuts-the-traditional-space-launch-snack/#.W_xZUPZFw2w)) passed out peanuts to calm people's nerves . . . and the landing was successful. Since then, it's become a tradition at JPL.

I've confirmed that peanuts have been consumed on the following missions (this is only a partial list, in all likelihood):

- *Ranger 7*, *Ranger 8* and *Ranger 9*<sup>[[1]](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/10022/lucky-peanuts/)</sup>
- *Cassini*<sup>[[1]](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/10022/lucky-peanuts/)</sup>
- *InSight*
- *Curiosity*<sup>[[2]](https://boingboing.net/2012/08/16/why-do-nasa-engineers-like-pea.html)</sup>
- India's *Mars Orbiter Mission*<sup>[[3]](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/6604/lucky-peanuts/)</sup>
- *Mariner*<sup>[[4]](https://books.google.com/books?id=LGYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=jpl+viking+peanuts&source=bl&ots=i7S45nBATV&sig=bl2nsWrZijzol3Bpev6b8-wGx3k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSxIX99vLeAhXPs1kKHStsBLMQ6AEwE3oECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=jpl%20viking%20peanuts&f=false)</sup>
- *Viking*<sup>[[5]](https://books.google.com/books?id=LGYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=jpl+viking+peanuts&source=bl&ots=i7S45nBATV&sig=bl2nsWrZijzol3Bpev6b8-wGx3k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSxIX99vLeAhXPs1kKHStsBLMQ6AEwE3oECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=jpl%20viking%20peanuts&f=false)</sup>
- *Pathfinder* (possibly)<sup>[[5]](https://books.google.com/books?id=LGYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=jpl+viking+peanuts&source=bl&ots=i7S45nBATV&sig=bl2nsWrZijzol3Bpev6b8-wGx3k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSxIX99vLeAhXPs1kKHStsBLMQ6AEwE3oECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=jpl%20viking%20peanuts&f=false)</sup>
- *Spirit*<sup>[[6]](https://www.nature.com/scientificamerican/journal/v290/n3/full/scientificamerican0304-52.html)</sup>

. . . and likely many more.

Comment: Can this be considered superstitious?

Comment: Yes, it can. So?