# What's up with the peanut tradition?

Tags: jpl

I was reading up on [Ranger 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranger_7) and at the very end a random bit of information is thrown in:

> The spacecraft performance was excellent and the success of the
>   mission finally brought a turnaround in NASA's fortunes after the
>   endless string of lunar probe failures since 1958.
>
> Ranger 7 is credited for beginning the "peanut" tradition at NASA
>   command stations. On the success of Ranger 7, someone in the control
>   room was noticed eating peanuts. Since 1964 control rooms ceremonially
>   open a container of peanuts for luck and tradition.

Which came from [a business insider article](https://www.businessinsider.com/nasas-mission-control-good-luck-peanuts-2012-8), which I don't really consider a good source on space news. Also found a short blurb from [NPR](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=3081033) and a few other scattered sources that make this seem like a "well-known tradition" such as this [Wikipedia section on JPL's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory#Peanuts_tradition).

[image]
*Check it out! Custom labeled peanuts for Cassini!*

I guess the over-all question here is, how did it really get started and is it still carried over into the future missions? Information on who started this tradition or initially made the superstitious (and possibly ironic) correlation between peanuts and success would also be welcomed. Also, maybe a note on whether or not this tradition is planned (or unplanned but in effect) for [Artemis-1](https://www.nasa.gov/artemis-1) would be a neat bit of information.

Comment: See the related [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32313/what-is-the-history-behind-having-peanuts-in-mission-control-during-critical-mis?rq=1)

Comment: JSC MCC is Atomic Fireball land https://balettie.com/mcc/atomic-fireballs/

Comment: @Uwe I have no idea how that didn't show up on the related questions list when I was posting... all it showed was "What is this peanut shaped building at JPL?". Thanks, definitely a duplicate.

Comment: @OrganicMarble hah that's awesome!